# Number of arbitrary constant

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The differential equation representing the family of ellipse having foci either on the $x$ axis or on the $y$ axis center at the origin and passing through the point $(0,3)$

So i wrote the general equation of ellipse :
$$\dfrac {x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac {y^2}{b^2} =1$$
then substituted $(0,3)$ so i got $b^2=9$
So my question is does this equation have two arbitrary constants or only one after finding the value of $b^2$
and also how many time should i differentiate this equation once or twice